# Understand how caret calculates a model performance in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to understand how caret calculates model performance.
To simplify things, I use the `lm` methods with the usual bootstrap (`boot`)
The default apparently gives 25 resamples.

I can't replicate the `R^2` and `RMSE` of the resamples.
I manually subsetted the train data to match the data used by the first resample and estimate the same regression. I repeated this test twice for the selected obs and holdouts.

None of these worked. I couldn't find what I miss in the documentation nor in earlier questions.

Edit: I managed to replicate the RMSE, still struggle with the other metrics.

```
library(caret)
df<-iris

##DATA PARTITIONING##
partition <- createDataPartition(df$Species, p = 0.5, list=FALSE ) # returns the indices of the train db.    
train.db<-df[partition,] 

# Linear regression
model.lm <- train(Sepal.Length~., 
                  data = train.db,
                  method="lm") 

model.lm$resample[1,] # These are the metrics I'm trying to replicate

boot1<-model.lm[["control"]][["index"]][["Resample01"]]
boot1.out<-model.lm[["control"]][["indexOut"]][["Resample01"]]

boot1.db<-train.db[boot1,] # Train set
boot1.db.oob<-train.db[boot1.out,] # test set

a<-lm(Sepal.Length~., data = boot1.db)
boot1.db.oob$yhat<-predict(a,newdata =boot1.db.oob )

#rmse
rmse<-sqrt(mean((boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length-boot1.db.oob$yhat)^2)) #RMSE

#R2
#TSS
tss<-sum((boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length-mean(boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length))^2)

#RSS
rss<-sum((boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length-boot1.db.oob$yhat)^2)

r2<-1-rss/tss

#MAE
mae<-median(abs(boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length-boot1.db.oob$yhat))


c(rmse,r2,mae)
model.lm$resample[1,] # RMSE is the same but the rest aren't
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to spot all the differences, posting here for the sake of others.

First, `MEA` is the mean absolute error rather than median absolute error.

The more important finding is about caret calculates the out-of-sample R.sq.

> A note about how R2 is calculated by caret: it takes the straightforward approach of computing the correlation between the observed and predicted values (i.e. R) and squaring the value. When the model is poor, this can lead to differences between this estimator and the more widely known estimate derived form linear regression models. Mostly notably, the correlation approach will not generate negative values of R2 (which are theoretically invalid). A comparison of these and other estimators can be found in Kvalseth 1985.

[link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html#measures-for-regression)

Here is the corrected code:

```
library(caret)
df<-iris

##DATA PARTITIONING##
partition <- createDataPartition(df$Species, p = 0.5, list=FALSE ) # returns the indices of the train db.    
train.db<-df[partition,] 

# Linear regression
model.lm <- train(Sepal.Length~., 
                  data = train.db,
                  method="lm") 

model.lm$resample[1,] # These are the metrics I'm trying to replicate

boot1<-model.lm[["control"]][["index"]][["Resample01"]]
boot1.out<-model.lm[["control"]][["indexOut"]][["Resample01"]]

boot1.db<-train.db[boot1,] # Train set
boot1.db.oob<-train.db[boot1.out,] # test set

a<-lm(Sepal.Length~., data = boot1.db)
boot1.db.oob$yhat<-predict(a,newdata =boot1.db.oob )

#rmse
rmse<-sqrt(mean((boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length-boot1.db.oob$yhat)^2))

#R2
r2_caret<-cor(boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length,boot1.db.oob$yhat)^2

#MAE
mae<-mean(abs(boot1.db.oob$Sepal.Length-boot1.db.oob$yhat))


c(rmse,r2_caret,mae)
model.lm$resample[1,]
```